# monthly data in python using yfinance

Tags: python, yahoo-finance

using the following code which gives the daily data. how do i get the monthly data instead.

```
import datetime
import yfinance as yf
tickers = ['AAPL', 'XOM']
start_date = datetime.date(2000, 1, 1)
end_date = datetime.date(2000, 4, 31)
daily_data = yf.download(tickers, start=start_date, end=end_date)  # definere datasættet
daily_data = daily_data['Adj Close'].dropna()
print(daily_data)
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
df = yf.download(tickers, start=start_date, end=end_date, interval='1mo')
```